# Why I'm not getting the smallest number from this array?

Tags: python

there's code i have

```
arr = ['2', '-2', '-3', '1']
x = min(arr)
print(x)
```

and the output is -2, but I want to get -3, I don't know why

Comment: The elements are strings not ints

Comment: because those are `str`s, not `int`s

Answer (score 2):

The elements of your array are strings, so `min` is returning the minimum result based on alphabetical comparison.

If you want to sort this particular array numerically, you could do something like

`x = min([int(i) for i in arr])`

Then `x` will have the value `-3`, as expected

Comment: I think you meant strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're passing in strings, not integers. When comparing strings, `-2` is smaller alphabetically than `-3`.
Change the array contents to integers and you should get your desired output.

```
arr = [2, -2, -3, 1]
x = min(arr)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method to map each string of the list to an integer:

```
arr = ['2', '-2', '-3', '1']
x = min(map(int, arr))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
-3
```